# What is the difference between "C:FILE.TXT" and "C:\FILE.TXT"?

Tags: windows, filesystems

What is the difference between "`C:FILE.TXT`" and "`C:\FILE.TXT`"?

Are they the same?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`C:FILE.TXT` refers to `FILE.TXT` in the current directory of drive `C:`

`C:\FILE.TXT` refers to `FILE.TXT` in the root directory of drive `C:` (`C:\`)

They are not the same.

**Edit: Command Prompt Example:**

Windows remembers a current working directory for each drive. Say you are working in directory `C:\UTILS` and then you change to drive `F:` and then to directory `BIN` on `F:`:

```
C:\UTILS> F:
F:\> CD BIN
F:\BIN>
```

At this point the current working directory for `C:` is still `C:\UTILS` and the current working directory for `F:` is `F:\BIN`

You can verifiy this with the `CD` command:

```
F:\BIN> CD C:
C:\UTILS

F:\BIN>
```

Note that you did not change the working drive back to `C:` by using this command.

As you will see from the following command examples, the use of a backslash (`\`) immediately after a drive name (`X:`) makes the file location absolute. Ommiting the backslash automatically involves the current working directory for the drive.

```
F:\BIN> COPY F:PROGRAM.EXE C:    Copies* F:\BIN\PROGRAM.EXE to C:\UTILS\PROGRAM.EXE
F:\BIN> COPY F:PROGRAM.EXE C:\   Copies* F:\BIN\PROGRAM.EXE to C:\PROGRAM.EXE
F:\BIN> COPY F:\PROGRAM.EXE C:   Copies* F:\PROGRAM.EXE to C:\UTILS\PROGRAM.EXE

F:\BIN> COPY F:PROGRAM.EXE C:NEW\NEW_PROG.EXE   Copies* and renames
                                                F:\BIN\PROGRAM.EXE
                                                to C:\BIN\NEW\NEW_PROG.EXE
```

* 'Copies' means 'attempts to copy'. These commands will fail if the assumed directory structures and current working directories don't exist or are changed by another process.

In the case where the working directory *is* the root directory (eg. `C:\`) then `C:PROGRAM.EXE` and `C:\PROGRAM.EXE` point to the same location, but they have been arrived at by different methods.

Comment: Actually they *can* be the same if C:’s current directory is the root.

Comment: @Synetech; Just because they can refer to the same place doesn't mean they're the same thing

Comment: Note that Windows NT doesn't track per-drive "current directories" anymore; this syntax is now only useful in the `cmd.exe` shell. In other programs, if a different drive than current is given, such path specifications will be always relative to that drive's root.

Comment: @Phoshi, yes, they are the same in certain contexts. It’s like saying that `int x` is the same as `int y`; they are not ===, but they *can* be == if both have the same value. @grawity, of course windows apps (Win32, not just NT) have [no per-drive cwd](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx) since it would mean nothing in that context. Regardless, it’s not just cmd; [all console apps have it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/06/10008132.aspx).

Comment: @Mike actually after reading through the answer i still can't tell the difference. could you elaborate it for a dumb user?

Comment: @Pacerier, I've added some examples for you.

Comment: @Synetech: If you actually read the article you linked to, you would have realized that it clearly states that they are "the private bookkeeping of the command processor cmd.exe".

Comment: @Hello71, did you read the **very first paragraph**? > *if you write a program that manually enumerates all the environment variables and prints them out, and if you launch it from a command prompt, then you'll see weird variables with names like =C:* Besides, I was not talking about the environment variables, I meant per-drive CWD.

Comment: @Synetech: Command prompt = cmd.exe

Comment: @Hello71, so/and?

Comment: @Synetech: "it’s not just cmd"

Comment: @Hello71, console != command-prompt; console is a *type* of app (“subsystem” in compiler parlance), *windowed* is another. The command-prompt/cmd just happens to be a console app.

Comment: @Synetechinc. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/950/discussion-between-hello71-and-synetech-inc)